# How to upgrade all global NPM packages to their latest non-breaking / minor version?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I try to update all global packages (including NPM itself) to their latest minor version of their current major version (so `current_major.x.x`).

`npm upgrade -g --force` will forcefully upgrade all global packages, including major versions, but this will break things for sure.

Is there a way? I know that I can upgrade all individual packages knowing their current major version, but I'd like to automate the process.

Comment: _Don't_ `--force`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe For me `--force` is necessary to [replace symlinks of global CLI binaries successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634657/how-do-i-fix-this-npm-install-conflict-between-existing-files-symlinks).

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to cherry-pick which parts of "force" you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for me, although, it will re-install existing packages, even when there was no version change.

```bash
npm_global_packages=($(npm list -g --depth 0 | awk '/ /{print $2}'))
for val in "${npm_global_packages[@]}"; do
    npm i -g --force $(echo $val | tr "." "\n" | head -1)
done
```

The `--force` option is to avoid symlink issues. Leaving it away will not solve unnecessary re-installs. I wonder if there is a smarter way, but that's what I will go for as of now.

### In depth

- `npm_global_packages` will be an array such as `npm@6.14.12 npx@10.2.2 pm2@5.2.0 rimraf@3.0.2`.
- `tr "." "\n" | head -1` will split each value by `.` and return only the first segment, so the script essentially would run `npm i -g --force npm@6`, `npm i -g --force npx@10`, ... which will re-install all packages on their same major version, although with the latest minor version.

Answer (score 0):

This command will analyze your global packages and print out a command you should run to update them all to latest:

```
npx npm-check-updates -g
```

Answer (score -1):

It's the same problem I had and I tried every solution I could find but finally found the answer in the documentation. You can update all packages with no side effects by:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

you can find more details [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-packages-downloaded-from-the-registry).

Comment: You misunderstood something, it says to update `npm` by running your snippet, but the actual script is linked [here](https://gist.github.com/othiym23/4ac31155da23962afd0e). The script itself will upgrade to the `latest` or `wanted` version, which might be another major version, so this is not what I asked about at all.